# AngularJS ng-grid with custom button

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am using angular button in a [ng-grid](http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/). I need to know how can i identity which button was clicked from within the grid.

I guess part of the complexity is that the button is clicked before the row is selected (Just my analysis,probably wont help with the solution :)

A snap shot of how the grid looks

[image: ng-grid]

A plunker illustrating the problem [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ynjrbx)

Answer (score 26):

I have been able to find out how to resolve my question,basically pass in "row" as an argument on your function for ng-click. ng-click="save(row)"

Before

```
.. ng-click="edit(selectedItem)" >Edit</button> '
```

After

```
.. ng-click="edit(row)" >Edit</button> '
```

I have updated the plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ynjrbx) to reflect the same

`row.entity` will give me the entity bound to this row of the grid

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Where did you find info on the entity object?

Comment: I am sorry, i have kind of lost touch with AngularJS, however i do remember looking it up on some blog and then having the same unanswered query, it would be great it someone could add to the answer

Comment: @Sudarshan Do you know how to prevent the row from being selected when you press the "edit" button?

Comment: I found `.entity` in the js debugger.  Yes, I'm taking a dependency on an undocumented property and am well aware of the risk.

Answer (score 5):

@Shai Aharoni You can prevent the row from being selected by passing $event as the first argument to the click handler:

```
.. ng-click="edit($event, row)">Edit</button>
```

and then calling stopPropagation() on the event from inside the handler.

```
$scope.edit = function(event, row) { event.stopPropagation(); }
```